# Change background color of webpage according to day of the week

Tags: php

I want to change the background color of my Homepage based on Day of the week.

For example :

On **Sunday** , **Monday** and **Tuesday** I want to change background of my homepage to **Blue** .

On **Thursday** I want to change it to **Gray** . on **Friday** to **Yellow** and on **Saturday** it should change to **Green** .

I have tried the following code on my website ,but it doesn't seem to work ,My background color is not changing, I tried to replace the value of **$day** with name of the week

```
 $day="Monday";
```

but it also didn't work.

**Here is my code**

```
 $day=date("l");
 if($day =="Sunday")
 {$bg_color="blue";}
 if($day =="Monday")
 {$bg_color="blue";} 
 if($day =="Tuesday")
 {$bg_color="blue";} 

 if($day =="Thursday")
 {$bg_color="gray";} 

 if($day =="Friday")
 {$bg_color="yellow";} 

 if($day =="Saturday")
 {$bg_color="Green";} 

 echo "<div style='background-color:$bg_color>Welcome to my Homepage</div>";
```

Comment: Aside from the quality of this code (which is terrible) it substitutes `$bg_color` correctly

Comment: valid html would help

Comment: You don't have a closing quote in `echo "<div style='background-color: $bg_color;'>Welcome to my Homepage</div>"`;

Comment: after 2.5k it would be nice if you could spot your own typos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It works for me. (Whenever you have too many if conditions like you have, think about using switch, instead.

```
<?php
$day=date("l");

switch($day) {
    case 'Monday':
        $bg_color = "red";
        break;
    case 'Tuesday':
        $bg_color = "blue";
        break;
    case 'Wednesday':
        $bg_color = "blue";
        break;
    case 'Thursday':
        $bg_color = "gray";
        break;
    case 'Friday':
        $bg_color = "yellow";
        break;
    case 'Saturday':
        $bg_color = "green";
        break;
    case 'Sunday':
    default:
        $bg_color = "black";
        break;
}

echo "<div style='background-color:$bg_color'>Welcome to my Homepage</div>";
```

### **YOUR ISSUE:**

**
Your code had missing the closing single quote `'` for style

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
echo "<div style='background-color:$bg_color;'>Welcome to my Homepage</div>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce your code using following code.

```
<?php
 $day=date("l");
 $bg_color_array = array('Sunday' => 'blue',
                       'Monday' => 'blue',
                       'Tuesday' => 'blue',
                       'Thursday' => 'gray',
                       'Friday' => 'yellow',
                       'Saturday' => 'green',
                 );
 // Wednesday is missing
 $bg_color =  isset($bg_color_array[$day]) ? $bg_color_array[$day] : 'black';
?> 
<?php echo "<div style='background-color:$bg_color;'>Welcome to my Homepapge</div>"; ?>
```